# Taking input from forms to assign a variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I write in a form to take in a number from the user and make a dice roll with the range of that number, where the variable "input" is their number.  I don't have enough experience with forms and all of the form tutorials are inline.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
result = Math.floor(((Math.random())* input))+1;
document.write(result);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific in terms of max and min if the dice has six sides the 1-6 is the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input id="txtInput" type="TextBox" onkeyup="myFunc();" />
</form>

<script>
function myFunc(){
    var input = document.getElementById("txtInput").value;
    result = Math.floor(((Math.random())* input))+1;
    document.write(result);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But also, how can I write the input form to recall that function when prompted?

Comment: That is what i'm looking for, but I was mainly asking how to make a button recall the function instead of refresh the page.

Comment: See above I edited to have an onkeyup event on the textbox. So every time the user lets up on a key the calculation in myFunc will execute.

Comment: If you want a button you just add a onclick event to the button to call myFunc

Comment: Excellent, it works!  But how would you write something to replace document.write() that would not erase everything else?

Comment: Create a output textbox if you want.   <input id="txtOutput" type="text" />

Comment: Then assign it a value document.getElementById("txtOutput").value = result;

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal and avoid document.write() that would erase everything, you can create a empty div, and then write the result to it. With this code you can repeat the operation of calling the random function as much times as you want:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

n: <input type="text" id="n" name="n" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="call_result();">

<div id="result"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function call_result(){
    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
    var result = Math.floor((Math.random())*input)+1;
//  document.write(result);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```